# Does Maya C++ API simply not give access to some tools?

Tags: c++, maya

For example, in Maya, we have the `Planar UV Mapping` tool in `UV > Planar`. I have not yet been able to find a class/function in the C++ API for Maya for this tool.

Is my only recourse calling the `mel` version through `executeCommand` or are these tools exposed in the C++ API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably read wrong, uv planner is tool set wrapper over [polyProjection](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/polyProjection.html) command. If you want to access those then you need to create it from scratch I think. using MfnMesh etc.. there are few example already available net to give some basic idea's how to do that. Here is one which not really a uv stuff but it will give you idea how it can be [done](http://www.fevrierdorian.com/blog/post/2011/07/31/Project-a-mesh-to-another-with-Maya-API-(English-Translation)) And there are some examples in [maya devkit](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-SDK/cpp_ref/flip_u_v_cmd_2flip_u_v_cmd_8cpp-example.html) too.

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 That does indeed help, thanks. Just to make sure I got it right, the `polyProjection` command is _not_ written in C++ and thus has no function to call in the C++ SDK?